# VB.NET -> C++ -> Java:- Calling Java functions from C++ - Code samples requested

Tags: vb.net

Here I am looking for a conceptual solution, plus some guidance. This is not an query that specifies an 'error in code/compilation/execution...' etc. Pl bear with the lengthy post.

My product is a desktop product written in VB.NET.

Another central team in office maintains a java code that does some computations, and releases jar to be used by whomever wants it. This team published APIs exposed by jar.

Users of this java jar were so far java developers, so everything was smooth so far.

Now, I am required to use the same jar and hence make calls to those exposed java APIs so that 'code is one, and used by any-and-many'.

Kindly pass on any useful links/code samples that helps me achieve this.

P.S. 
1. I do not have a chance to go to any third party tools to make the bridge between Java & .net.

1. I am getting little bit understanding about JNI for such purposes, but am not getting a solid code sample that explains what should I do on C++ side to make a call to java functions.
2. And my team could put efforts to call C++ wappers from VB.NET

Thanks in advance,